# SSIS SQL Step Seems to fail

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package (ss2k12) I'm working on which begins with a SQL task to check if a table exists, create it if it doesn't, then truncates it. The table is a work table for a Data Flow task that follows.

When I run the task, it works. When I run the package (after deleting the table...) it fails looking for the missing table (which the sql task creates if it's missing....) Is this because it's "pre-checking" the data flow task? How do I get around the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a package receives the signal to start, the SSIS engine looks at every component and verifies that it exists, the meta data signatures match, etc. Then, when the component gets the signal that it can run, the metadata is then rechecked prior to execution.

To get around this issue, you need to use the `DelayValidation` property to indicate that validation should *only* occur when it is ready to execute.

Depending on how your package is structured, you might need to set this at both the Task (Data Flow) as well as the Package (control flow) level.